# React-medium-editor not working in Material UI dialog box

Tags: reactjs, medium-editor

I am trying to implement rich text in a dialog box which I picked from Material-UI. For doing so I am using a package react-medium-editor. If I place it inside dialog box it does not convert the text to rich text but outside the dialog box it does.
What can be the problem
Here is the sample project that I made to demonstrate.

[Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-lefxm?file=/demo.js)

Answer (score 0):

You can make react-medium-editor work with Material-UI's Dialog by setting the prop: `disableEnforceFocus` to `true`.

```
<Dialog 
    disableEnforceFocus 
    open={open} 
    onClose={() => handleClose()
    {...otherDialogProps}
 >
     // Dialog Content
</Dialog>
```

WARNING: According to [Material-UI's docs](https://material-ui.com/api/modal/#props) on `disableEnforceFocus`:

> If `true`, the modal will not prevent focus from leaving the modal while
> open.

> Generally this should never be set to `true` as it makes the modal
> less accessible to assistive technologies, like screen readers.